# How to calculate the linear and angular velocity acceleration based an acting force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

[image: Examples]

In the first example there is an actig force perpendicular to the direction of the center of mass, resulting in an linear velocity acceleration in the direction of the force.

in the second example there is an acting force which is not perpendicular to the center of mass, resulting in an acceleration of linear and angular velocity.

i know what would be happening (or correct me if i don't), but not how i could calculate it?!

Answer (score 0):

You have to balance forces and moments separately.

The linear motion is governed by:

$$\Sigma F_y = ma_y$$

And the rotation is governed by:

$$ \Sigma M_O = I\alpha$$

Where you have to choose a point $O$ about which to sum the moments $M$.  The moment due to a force is the force magnitude times the distance $L$ from the point $O$.  So for example your moment summation would look like:

$$ LF_y = I\alpha$$

(In your case there is only one source of moment)

Comment: What is $M_2$ and $M_3$?

Comment: In this case zero, but I was going for the generic equation. But on second thought I got rid of them

Comment: ΣFy=may

does that mean that the amount of the linear acceleration is independed of the direction that the force is applied ?

Comment: Of course not. "y" is what I decided to can the vertical direction in your figure. If you want to use vector form it would be $\vec F=m \vec a$

Comment: I don't understand, 
if m = 1 then  F⃗ =1a⃗ ,  then the magnitude of the the linear acceleration would always be equal to the magnitude of  F⃗, Right?

Comment: The force and acceleration always point in the same direction. They are vector quantities. Otherwise you would have situations where you push something forward and it accelerates to the right, which is absurd (violating conservation of momentum).  Within the context of the same direction, then the scalar magnitudes obey $F=ma$

Comment: Understood it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### 2D Equations of Motion

Tracking the center of mass $(x_C,y_C)$ and rotation $\theta$ based on the net force components $(F_x,F_y)$ and net torque about the center of mass $\tau_C$

$$ \begin{aligned}
 m \ddot{x}_C & = F_x \\
 m \ddot{y}_C & = F_y \\
 I_C \ddot{\theta} & = \tau_C 
\end{aligned} $$

where $I_C$ is the mass moment of inertia about the center of mass.

If the loading on the body is a single vertical force $F$ that is offset by $d$ from the center of mass, then

$$ \left. \begin{aligned}
 m \ddot{x}_C & = 0 \\
 m \ddot{y}_C & = F \\
 I_C \ddot{\theta} & = d\,F 
\end{aligned} \right\} \begin{aligned}    \ddot{x}_C & = 0 \\
 \ddot{y}_C & = \tfrac{F}{m} \\
 \ddot{\theta} & = \tfrac{ d\,F}{I_C}  \end{aligned} $$